# get values from string when characters are involved

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in which I want to get the both the values "12345" and "123.5" from and put it into a collection so I can loop through and do something with it. Can someone help with this?

```
string test = "Hello World [12345] - [123.5]"

string anothertest = "Hello World [A12345 (05,00,45)] [518.6Z] [51.5]"
```

I would like "A12345" "518.6Z" "51.5"

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? Do you mean that you want "12345" and "123.5" to be two items in a collection, or that you want each character in those two strings to be items in a collection? Do you care what kind of collection?

Comment: @Melanie - I want tow items in a collection not each characters.

Comment: are brackets 'well formed' - open/closed, no nested etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following regex:

```
\[(\d+\.?\d+)\]
```

You'll want group(1).

Maybe this semi-pseudo will help...

```
Regex expression = new Regex(@"\[(\d+\.?\d+)\]");
var results = expression.Matches(test);
foreach (Match match in results)
{
    //do whatever you want.
}
```

Comment: can you explain to me what \[(\d+\.?\d+)\] mean? I mean like a break down?

Comment: \\[ means [. ( begins a matching group. \d matches digits. + means one or more of the thing before. thus, \d+ means one or more digits. \. means "."  - ? matches none or 1. as in \.? matches zero or more periods. this will help: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Comment: thanks for the link you've provided. Can you help with this? "Hello World [A12345 (05,00,45)] [518.6Z] [51.5]" .. I would like "A12345" "518.6Z" "51.5"...

Answer (score 0):

For the second part you edited in:

```
\[(\d*\w*\.?\d*\w*)(?!\()
```

The "?!" is a negative lookahead assertion which in this case means "match the things before that are not followed by a ("